# Is the usage of "one" instead of an article in a sentence meant for stressing on the importance of the following noun?

Tags: articles

"It is one model which is gaining reputation recently. "

In the above-mentioned sentence,  can't we replace "one" with "a". Why do we sometimes write it as "one"? Kindly give me better clarity.

Comment: "There are two models which are gaining reputation recently."  "One" is simply a number.

Comment: You can replace *one* with *a*, but *one* does tend to more directly suggest *one among many*.

Comment: When you use *one*, you are contrasting a particular model with other models, some of which are gaining reputation, while others, perhaps most, are not. *There is something about the recent gain in reputation of this one model that stands out in comparison to other models.* When you use *a*, you lose this sense of contrast by virtue of noteworthiness. You are simply stating a fact about the model under discussion, i.e., that it happens to be one model among a set of models that has been gaining reputation recently, without there being anything particularly noteworthy about it.

Answer (score 1):

There is the 'one of several [in a subset]' sense, where 'a' doesn't carry this connotation so strongly:

- Although many new models are not gaining popularity, there are several that buck the trend. Consider the Zeta Supervac. It is one model which is gaining reputation recently.

But there is also another usage – as you hint, an *emphasising* usage – one of a kind even [in the universal set] where 'a' would sound weak:

- Although hardly any new models are gaining popularity, consider the Zeta Supervac. It is one model which *is* gaining reputation recently.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the use of *one* implies that there are more than one model that are gaining reputation recently and the number of models is within countable range, while the use of *a* implies there are many more models that are gaining reputation recently.

Comment: It is one model which is gaining reputation recently; It is one of the models which is gaining reputation recently; It is a model which is gaining reputation recently. None of these are wrong. When the number needs to be emphasized, 'one' is used.  Consider slightly modifying the sentence as //It is a model that is gaining popularity recently.//

Comment: I didn't say any of the variations is wrong but in my opinion, each of the sentences above does have different implication.